# Separate apps for different modules or all-in-one

Tags: node.js, module, sencha-touch-2

I'm building an app, with Sencha Touch and NodeJS as a backend. This app is supposed to be used to control and report the whereabouts of public transport in a city. I'm planning to have three modules built, one for the passenger, one for the driver and one administrative module.

What I'm thinking is, should I build all these modules in the same app and check for user profiles at log-in? Or should I build separate apps (at least to separate the general user module from the other two) to make it more secure.

If the passenger somehow got access to any of the other modules it would obviously be extremely harmful.

Answer (score 0):

The first reason to have 3 different modules is what you have pointed out - security.

The second reason to do so is - what if one of the services fails - as 1 large codebase it brings the whole lot down - as 3 different services, 66% of your service is still working.

The third reason is KISS - keep things simple stupid - one big codebase is harder to reason about and model.  Bugs affect the whole codebase.  Adding features becomes a trade off between the services.

Generally I would say to not only split your app into 3 modules but to take this approach down to a much lower level and try to split things into 'single components' as much as possible.

Think about a carpenter making a table to order (what most software devs are doing is 'to order').

The carpenter does not download a 'table making' library as one large codebase.

They first use the 'saw' program to saw wood.

Then the 'sanding' program to smooth wood.

Then the 'Hammer' program to put wood together - etc etc

Notice how each step is one tool doing one job.

The next day the carpenter is asked to make a chair - they use the same tools in a different order.

This is the [Unix Philosphy](http://www.faqs.org/docs/artu/ch01s06.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would say that dividing the access to different information is an application layer concern and I would build it all into the same node.js app. This app should check with the user permissions if that type of user has access to the information it is requesting.